# What could go wrong if I let users create their own Mongo collections?

Tags: security, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am in the process of building a basic no-code solution to build RESTful APIS that support CRUD operations on a MongoDB collection. Right now it is just a Proof of Concept project that I use internally with no external users.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56004918/how-to-create-mongodb-schema-dynamically-using-nodejs) on Stack Overflow the other day and I though that it could allow me to convert this little project into a SaaS concept.

Allowing users to create their own collections in MongoDB could be potentially insecure, but I couldn't think of any catastrophic consequence... Maybe the fact that malicious users can purposely create a collection that is horrible in performance? Or maybe the user could inject some references to other collections...?

Does having a separated Mongo database help to mitigate those attacks? Or could you give me more reasons why this is a bad idea?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

A few problems I can think of

1. Duplicate collection names
2. Unwanted characters
3. Performance issue is there as you might not be able to control the indexes

A different approach would be you create the collection for them and let them put the data into a `mixed` field. Still you will face the `indexing` problem at some extend.